# Merging two notification observers in RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactivex

I have this piece of code:

```
let appActiveNotifications: [Observable<NSNotification>] = [
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().rx_notification(UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification),
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().rx_notification(Constants.AppRuntimeCallIncomingNotification)
]

appActiveNotifications.merge()
  .takeUntil(self.rx_deallocated)
  .subscribeNext() { [weak self] _ in
  // notification handling
}
.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

It's supposed to listen to either of the specified notifications and handle when any of them is triggered.

However this does not compile. I get the following error:

```
Value of type '[Observable<NSNotification>]' has no member 'merge'
```

How should I merge these two signals to one then?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`.merge()` combines multiple `Observables` so you'll want to do `appActiveNotifications.toObservable()` then call `.merge()` on it

**Edit:**
Or as the example in the [RxSwift's playground](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/a1c2448efe88e45e6fe0818df351b9cdefe41709/Rx.playground/Pages/Combining_Observables.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift#L205), you can use `Observable.of()` then use `.merge()` on it; like so:

```
let a = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().rx_notification(UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification)
let b = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().rx_notification(Constants.AppRuntimeCallIncomingNotification)

Observable.of(a, b)
  .merge()
  .takeUntil(self.rx_deallocated)
  .subscribeNext() { [weak self] _ in
     // notification handling
  }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: I want to merge 2 different type of Observers. Any idea how to achieve? This is what I'm trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050059/rxswift-merge-different-kind-of-observables

Comment: You can't merge 2 different types of Observables. You have to convert on of them or both to make a match !

Comment: @SwiftHipster you can use `zip` to get both results and merge it manually

Comment: if it's possible, map them to the same type, e.g.

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().rx_notification(UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification).map({ _ in true}_`