# RxSwift merge different kind of Observables

Tags: swift, frp, rx-swift

How should I merge 2 different types of `Observable`s in RxSwift?

For example:

```
var a: Observable<Int>
var b: Observable<Void>
```

`Observable.of(a,b).merge()` is not possible because of type parameter difference.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To `merge` them, they need to have the same type for their `Element`.

So, one option is to throw away their type information and cast to `AnyObject`. Now they can be merged:

```
let stringSubject = PublishSubject<String>()
let stringObservable = stringSubject.asObservable().map { $0 as AnyObject }

let intSubject = PublishSubject<Int>()
let intObservable = intSubject.asObservable().map { $0 as AnyObject }

Observable.of(stringObservable, intObservable).merge()
    .subscribeNext { print($0) }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

stringSubject.onNext("a")
stringSubject.onNext("b")
intSubject.onNext(1)
intSubject.onNext(2)
stringSubject.onNext("c")
```

Output:

> a
>   b
>   1
>   2
>   c

Another option would be to wrap then in an enum:

```
enum Container {
    case S(String)
    case I(Int)
}

let stringSubject = PublishSubject<String>()
let stringObservable = stringSubject.asObservable().map { Container.S($0) }

let intSubject = PublishSubject<Int>()
let intObservable = intSubject.asObservable().map { Container.I($0) }

Observable.of(stringObservable, intObservable).merge()
    .subscribeNext { e in
        switch e {
        case .S(let str):
            print("next element is a STRING: \(str)")
        case .I(let int):
            print("next element is an INT: \(int)")
        }
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

stringSubject.onNext("a")
stringSubject.onNext("b")
intSubject.onNext(1)
intSubject.onNext(2)
stringSubject.onNext("c")
```

Output:

> next element is a STRING: a
>   next element is a STRING: b
>   next element is an INT: 1
>   next element is an INT: 2
>   next element is a STRING: c

As for the other operators that can combine `Observable`s of varying types (like `zip` and `combineLatest`), none work quite like `merge`. However, check those out. They might be better suited to your requirements.

Answer (score 6):

In case you want to merge two observables but you don't need the value of `Element` and want a way to get rid of the `Expression of type 'AnyObject' is unused` when using the `.map { $0 as AnyObject }` option:

```
var a = PublishSubject<Int>()
var b = PublishSubject<Void>()

let observable = Observable.merge(a.map { _ in return Void() }, b)
```