# RxSwift array of Variable with different types

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, rx-swift

I am trying to define an array of Rxswift Variable which is of different types (Int, String, Bool, String?, etc...)

So technically I want something like this,

```
var intVariable = Variable<Int>(10)
var stringVariable = Variable<String>("Hello, RxSwift")
let genericArray = [intVariable, stringVariable]
```

Reason for this is that, I have a list of variables that i want to subscribe on.

However, i can subscribe on the variables individually like `intVariable.asObservable().subscribe`, `stringVariable.asObservable().subscribe` and so on. 
But if its in an array, I could loop through all the elements and subscribe on it.

The Rxswift Variable is defined as `public final class Variable<Element>`

P.S I have tried type erasure but no luck. Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: I doubt that it is possible? What is the case in which you need to subscribe to variables of different type?

Comment: instead of making a loop to subscribe to each individual observable, I suggest to subscribe once to merged sequence of observables. Since you have different type of variables, you could perform a workaround as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050059/rxswift-merge-different-kind-of-observables

Comment: Thanks @Nimble, works great for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do here depends entirely on what that `subscribe` closure looks like. If you are doing the same thing to every item in either variable, regardless of type then just map them both to the same type:

```
let bag = DisposeBag()
let intVariable = Variable<Int>(10)
let stringVariable = Variable<String>("Hello, RxSwift")
let genericArray = Observable.merge([intVariable.asObservable().map { "\($0)" }, stringVariable.asObservable()])
genericArray.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) }).disposed(by: bag)
intVariable.value = 5
stringVariable.value = "Goodby, RxSwift"
```

prints:

```
10
Hello, RxSwift
5
Goodby, RxSwift
```

If you are combining the two items in some way where you need the most recent emitted of each variable and you need to keep the type information then do this:

```
let genericArray = Observable.combineLatest(intVariable.asObservable(), stringVariable.asObservable())
```

prints:

```
(10, "Hello, RxSwift")
(5, "Hello, RxSwift")
(5, "Goodby, RxSwift")
```

If you only want your subscribe to be triggered when a new element is emitted from *both* variables, then:

```
let genericArray = Observable.zip(intVariable.asObservable(), stringVariable.asObservable())
```

which prints:

```
(10, "Hello, RxSwift")
(5, "Goodby, RxSwift")
```

I would avoid the solutions mentioned in ([RxSwift merge different kind of Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050059/rxswift-merge-different-kind-of-observables))

Comment: Thanks @Daniel T , the problem i saw with `combineLatest` and `zip` is that it is limited to 8 arguments and not generic.
I feel the first option (with merge) would be the best option for my case, reason being, i just need to listen for updates and run `invalidateLayout` on any change.

Comment: They absolutely are generic. If you have more than 8 arguments, the use combines of combines or zips of zips.