# How to observe multiple variables for .next event while ignoring values in RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a class with the `Variable` properties `number` and `text` and want to observe any changes done on both variables. The values of these properties are not needed.

In my **real case** I have **more than 10** `Variables` to observe, so maybe it should be possible to pass them **as an array of** `.asObservable()`.

```
let number: Variable<Int>

let text:   Variable<String>

func doSomethingWhenAnyValueWasChanged() {
    // some code
}
```

How do I achieve that?

I tried to do it with `Observable.combineLatest()` in multiple ways, but it didn't work out for me. Maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) it looks like Combine Latest would be your best option.

> **CombineLatest**
>
> when an item is emitted by either of two Observables, combine the
>   latest item emitted by each Observable via a specified function and
>   emit items based on the results of this function.

```
let number: Variable<Int>

let text:   Variable<String>

_ = Observable.combineLatest(number.asObservable(), text.asObservable()) { x, y in
       doSomethingWhenAnyValueWasChanged()
}
```

Comment: And when I do the same, but passing the observables as an array, I get a compile error: `contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, which cannot be implicitly ignored`

Comment: yeah i've just checked that in a playground, its just saying you need to use the variable name in the closure, like  `{ x in }` or you could use `{ _ in }` if you dont need the variable

Comment: yes, this works, and I now found a way to pass Observers as an array: `Observable.combineLatest([number.asObservable().map { $0 as AnyObject}, text.asObservable().map { $0 as AnyObject } ])` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050059/rxswift-merge-different-kind-of-observables)). But I really wish there would be a nicer way.